# Make text bold when mouse hovers over Context menu

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, contextmenu, highlighting

I am wondering how to change the text when the mouse hovers over text in a context menu? I want the text to become Bold but not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated :). This is my resource style for the menu Items containing an image, which is where I think I should put it

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemIcon" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ContentSource" Value="Icon">
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>                   
            </Style>    
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following :

```
 <Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" x:Shared="False">
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Regards,

Comment: I get an error "The member FontWeight is not recognized or accessible" :(

Comment: That's surprising.. I tested it and it works for me.. Did you place this inside a resource merged dictionary?

Comment: I placed this inside my usercontrol.resources, I'm guessing this is a big difference?

Comment: I think it should be done at the top level, unless the scope of the context menu is just for that user control. In any case I wasn't expecting "The member FontWeight is not recognized or accessible".

Comment: OK so I put it at the top level and get this error now : The resource "x:Type MenuItem}" could not be resolved.

Comment: Have you referenced  PresentationFramework.dll  at the top level ?

Comment: I'm not sure how do I reference that?

Comment: Click on Add Reference ->> Select  PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: Yeah I just checked and I have referenced this

Comment: It does work as I have another context menu that I just tested it on and it does work, but it doesn't work for my main context menu and I don't know why or how to add it into my style that I have already created which is above, can you hep?

Comment: Well, if you put this in App.xaml resource dictionary, it should apply for all context menus.

Comment: Thanks so much :), one final quick question do you know how to edit the highlight background? The current highlight when the mouse is hovered over is blue but I would like to change it to yellow

Answer (score 0):

To answer your another question, to change hover background please use the following :

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}" x:Shared="False">
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I have exactly that and there is no change at all

Comment: Nope nothing happened :(

Comment: Are you using any infragistic / Devexpress controls by any chance . They have different menu theme and it might be creating issue.... I am not exactly sure though...

Comment: I'm using syncfusion, which I'm guessing does make a difference?

Comment: So just created a standard program and still no change happening at all :(

Comment: The bold for text works fine on my standard program just now the Highlight